# Why does the Hamiltonian of a Lagrangian that consists of only a coupled term become zero?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, constrained-dynamics

Let's say our Lagrangian looks something like this:

$$L = \int dz\, Q\cdot \dot{A},\tag{1}$$

where $Q$ and $A$ are two generalized coordinates and $\dot{Q}$ and $\dot{A}$ would be the respective time-derivatives. If I wanted to Legendre-transform this, then considering the conjugate momenta 
$$P_Q = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{Q}} = 0\tag{2}$$ and 
$$P_A = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{A}} = Q\tag{3}$$ 
the Hamiltonian becomes:

$$H = P_Q\dot{A}-L= \int dz\,\, Q\cdot \dot{A} - Q\cdot \dot{A} = 0.\tag{4}$$

Is this correct? What does that even mean for the physical system?

Comment: possible duplicates: [Dirac equation as Hamiltonian system](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43502/84967), [Why is the Hamiltonian zero in relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/305178/84967), [My Hamiltonian for a light ray vanishes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/264853/84967).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the purpose of the Legendre transformation from Lagrangian to Hamiltonian formalism is to bring the equations of motion on first-order form. This is where the [Faddeev-Jackiw method](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9306075) is so much simpler [than the traditional Dirac-Bergmann analysis which OP just performed]: OP's Lagrangian $Q\dot{A}$ is already on first-order form $p\dot{q}-H$ if we identify
$$ q~=~A,\qquad p~=~Q,\qquad H~=~0~!$$
A vanishing Hamiltonian means that all phase space variables are constants of motion. It reflects the world-line (WL) reparametrization invariance of the action, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/449169/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/305178/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

Comment: what does this mean for the physical system? If the Hamiltonian is zero, isn't the energy also zero?

Comment: I updated the answer.